# Multiple upload in c# net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload

After saving information from a page in c# net 4.0 I need to add some pics in multiple mode.

I can't use net 4.5.

The problem :

If I open the page with multiple upload in the browser IE 11 this works correctly, and you can select multiple pics to upload.

If I open the same page as multiple upload in a window popup on IE 11, you can't select multiple pics to upload, but only a pic.

What's the problem ?

My code below, thank you in advance.

**.aspx markup (Default.aspx)**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Panel ID="upload01" runat="server" CssClass="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
            <fieldset style="margin-left: 50px">
                <legend style="font-weight: bold; color: Red; margin-left: 10px;">PICS</legend>
                <div class="pure-g">
                    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
                        <label for="Pics">Pics</label>

                        <p>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" multiple="true" runat="server" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Button ID="btUpload" Text="Upload Files"
                                    OnClick="Upload_Files" runat="server" />
                            </p>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFileList" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUploadStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFailedStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</form>
```

**.cs code-behind**

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'Default.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);
}
```

**EDIT #1**

```
protected void Upload_Files(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (upload01.HasFile)     // CHECK IF ANY FILE HAS BEEN SELECTED.
        {
            int iUploadedCnt = 0;
            int iFailedCnt = 0;
            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            lblFileList.Text = "Select <b>" + hfc.Count + "</b> file(s)";

            if (hfc.Count <= 10)    // 10 FILES RESTRICTION.
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= hfc.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists(Server.MapPath("\\images\\") + 
                            Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)))
                        {
                            DirectoryInfo objDir = 
                                new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("\\images\\"));

                            string sFileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                            string sFileExt = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);

                            // CHECK FOR DUPLICATE FILES.
                            FileInfo[] objFI = 
                                objDir.GetFiles(sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, "") + ".*");

                            if (objFI.Length > 0)
                            {
                                // CHECK IF FILE WITH THE SAME NAME EXISTS (IGNORING THE EXTENTIONS).
                                foreach (FileInfo file in objFI)
                                {
                                    string sFileName1 = objFI[0].Name;
                                    string sFileExt1 = Path.GetExtension(objFI[0].Name);

                                    if (sFileName1.Replace(sFileExt1, "") == 
                                            sFileName.Replace(sFileExt, ""))
                                    {
                                        iFailedCnt += 1;        // NOT ALLOWING DUPLICATE.
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // SAVE THE FILE IN A FOLDER.
                                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("\\images\\") + 
                                    Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                                iUploadedCnt += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                lblUploadStatus.Text = "<b>" + iUploadedCnt + "</b> file(s) Uploaded.";
                lblFailedStatus.Text = "<b>" + iFailedCnt + 
                    "</b> duplicate file(s) could not be uploaded.";
            }
            else lblUploadStatus.Text = "Max. 10 files allowed.";
        }
        else lblUploadStatus.Text = "No files selected.";
    }
```

Comment: Whats in Upload_Files ?

Comment: @BugFinder Hi thanks please see **EDIT #1** in my first question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong for this problem

Please see this, I hope this help.

[Click here](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/file/fileupload-csharp/#/)